# chat suspension?

Tags: support, chat

I could not figure out how to change my keyboard layout from Workman (which I have been trying to learning) back to QWERTY. Google found no results for my query (it usually automatically corrects wrong layouts) and I resorted to asking in chat. Sadly I was flagged many times and my chat account was suspended.

http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33336956#33336956

As you can see, I was just confused. Is there a way to reverse this chat suspension?

Comment: The messages you claim to have sent in this question are, in fact, wildly different from [the messages you actually sent](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33336956#33336956).

Comment: @Doorknob The version in the question is in fact the unscrambled version provided by ASCII-only.

Comment: Maybe you should actually type in a real language, lol. Go through the alphabet until you find the letter you're *actually* looking for, rather than typing based on the keys from QWERTY when you're using a different layout.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this doesn't help future readers because hopefully it's common intuition not to type gibberish, regardless of whether or not there's a keyboard layout change.

Comment: Why did you think typing in workman in chat was going to help? Just use a different device to look up your problem or carry on trying to use Google

Comment: @BetaDecay I have no idea. This happened over half a year ago. I shouldn't have made a meta question for a suspension this short.

Comment: @BetaDecay  Honestly I'd really like this question to be purged from SE. I know that's not going to happen though.

Comment: Well it'll probably be deleted soon since it's been closed and has a -10 score so that's half the way there

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Workman or no Workman, you littered TNB with gibberish. One of your posts got flag-deleted, which results in an automatic 30 minute suspension.

The suspension will wear off in 10 minutes.

Comment: OK, thanks. Completely understandable.